# locationManager Unwrapping Error in Swift 4.1 but not in Swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, option-type

I have code that I wrote in Swift 4.0 allowing an App which I am working on to show a Map with a destination and a user location. Now this app worked perfectly before the the recent update to Swift 4.1.

The error message says that there is an unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. In the xCode output window it is showing the following text:

Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4
(lldb)

I have tried all sorts of things, and looked this up all over the internet and I am not sure wether this is a bug in Swift 4.1 or there is something new I need to do. Like said, this app worked perfectly before.

I also made sure the info.plist has the right Privacy properties applied for Location Manager.

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npTlc.png)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBAction func centerUserLocation(_ sender: Any) {
    mapkitView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.follow, animated: true)
}

    @IBOutlet weak var mapkitView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBAction func phoneNumber(_ sender: Any) {
    let number = "00436641491000"
    if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(number)") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    }
}

@IBAction func emailAddress(_ sender: Any) {
    let email = "salzburg@citybeats.at"
    if let url = URL(string: "mailto:\(email)") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapkitView.delegate = self
    mapkitView.showsScale = true
    mapkitView.showsPointsOfInterest = true
    mapkitView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapkitView.userTrackingMode = .follow

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    let sourceCoordinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate
    let destCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(47.800715, 13.041061)

    let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceCoordinates!)
    let destPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destCoordinates)

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = destCoordinates
    annotation.title = "CityBeats"
    annotation.subtitle = "House & RnB"

    mapkitView.addAnnotation(annotation)



    let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
    let destItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlacemark)

    let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    directionRequest.source = sourceItem
    directionRequest.destination = destItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .walking

    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculate(completionHandler: {
        response, error in

        guard let response = response else {
            if let error = error {
                print("Something went wrong!")
            }
            return
        }

        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.mapkitView.add(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

        let rekt = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapkitView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rekt), animated: true)
    })
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.cyan
    renderer.alpha = 0.7
    renderer.lineWidth = 7.0

    return renderer
    }
}
```

Comment: The only place I see in YOUR code that would complain about unwrapping nil is when you use "sourceCoordinates!", which is fairly dangerous really.  You should make sure that isn't nil beforehand when getting it from locationManager (instead of force unwrapping it).

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? ghostaron's guess seems like a strong candidate, but you shouldn't post dozens of lines of code and ask for help with an error without telling which line is throwing the error.

Comment: I am really sorry I forgot to add the screen shot, I did take it to show which line throws the error. Thanks for your advice and help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if `sourceCoordinates` is nil.

e.g.

```
guard let sourceCoordinates = locationManager.location?.coordinate else {
    return
}
```